# PFUser Trouble Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I added a Col to my PFUser which is type Array which I named Friends.

I want to be able to add a string to this array and I am attempting to do so by doing

```
let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        //Do some other stuff

       var query = PFUser.query()
       query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: inputTextField!.text)
       var friend = query!.findObjects()

        if friend!.isEmpty{
            var alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Username Does Not Exist"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Done")
            alert.show()

        }
        else{
            println(friend)
            println(inputTextField!.text)

           //  currentUser?.addObject(inputTextField!.text, forKey: "Friends")
           //  currentUser?["Friends"] = inputTextField!.text

        }
    }
```

I commented the two lines which I believe one of the two could sole my problem however neither of them are working for me.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Describe what each of the commented lines does wrong. Why do you want an array of strings instead of a relationship?

Comment: Im not sure how to use relationship, but essentially I want to be able to see all the Friends of a user, where Friendship does not need to be mutual. But on the parse side the array of Friends never gets updated although it does run and compile just fine.

Comment: Well, you aren't saving the user after making a change. But you should look at using a relationship, it's the appropriate data type, not Array

Comment: You really should not be doing a synchronous find on the main thread. That will block your UI.

Comment: not sure what currentuser is here but as its an optional try using an if let statement to unwrap it before using it